# Start process in PowerShell, dehydrate it's data and detach from it

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, start-process

I am trying to start NodeJS package remotely from TeamCity PowerShell build step.

Currently, a part that starts the process looks like this:

```
$npm = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
$params = $pathToStart

$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $npm -ArgumentList $params -Passthru
$proc | Export-Clixml -Path $fullProcessHandlePath
```

$pathToStart indeed holds path to my package's entry point. When I run it with -Wait, effectively causing my PS script to never end, I can see that the node package is started and is executing correctly. However, if I let the script run to the point of

```
$proc | Export-Clixml -Path $fullProcessHandlePath
```

and exit, my node process gets terminated as well.

I need to call the Export-Clixml to save the newly created processes handle info so that I could later of destroy it from another script.

How can I keep Export-Clixml, but detach from ps script and let node.exe work on?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) package to have node.js code to create a windows service for my application. I know this is kind of different thing and I will not mark it as an answer, although knowing that I couldn't get node.exe to stay alive even with Start-Job may save someone's day and lead to a more solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making use of the Start-Job cmdlet rather than Start-Process as it will allow you to detach the PowerShell console from the command run.

```
$npm = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
$params = $pathToStart

Start-Job -FilePath $npm -ArgumentList $params
```

As for pulling the process information the best I could come up with is to run get the most recent node process via sorting by time, this will get as granular as the millisecond the process was launched.

```
Get-Process notepad | Sort-Object starttime | Select-Object -Last 1 | Export-Clixml -Path $fullProcessHandlePath
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that Start-Job tells me I should specify another ps1 script is a value for -FilePath. If I do via code block, I end up calling Start-Process in it.

Comment: I've spend an hour trying to run node from $scriptBlock that is started via Start-Job and it acts as a blackbox. I run it, pass params and nothing. When I monitor the processes spanned by PowerShell user that is calling Invoke-Command to execute this all on a machine, I see that it creates a powershell process, two more conhost and something else, but never even tries to run node.exe. 

I suspect the code in my script block never executes.

Comment: here is an exact error with your example: The value of the FilePath parameter must be a Windows PowerShell script file. 
Enter the path to a file with a .ps1 file name extension and try the command again.